Questions About Authoritative Catholic Interpretations of Scripture
See my answer here for context. I've seen a number of questions of the same kind over the years participating on this site, and I wonder if a rule might be needed to address these kinds of questions in general.
Generally, Catholic exegesis does not look to an authoritative statement from the Catholic Church which says that a particular verse or passage must be interpreted in a certain way. Rather, Catholic exegetes may not contradict authoritative teachings of the Catholic Church in their exegesis, but are free to differ from one another regarding how they exegete, even having contradictory opinions on the meaning of certain passages, so long as neither contradicts the Church's doctrines. Good exegetes will also look to the Church Fathers (who we know sometimes disagree about the meaning of certain passages of Scripture, and do not disagree on others), as well as biblical commentaries from reputable Catholic theologians in history, especially Saints, and most especially those Saints given the title of "Doctor."
Whenever I see a question asking for the official Catholic interpretation of a passage, I think that what I've explained above is the correct answer. There is not an official Catholic interpretation of almost all of Scripture (certain verses, though very few in number, may have been authoritatively interpreted by a council or something), so that questions of this form contain a false, implicit premise that can make it difficult to give a satisfying, thorough, on-topic answer to the question without simply repeating this.

Yeah, there's a lot of general questions that could have the same answer over and over again "Why does God permit evil?"  etc... I think you should get to the root of the question and overlook the request for official Church documents especially when there are almost never any.
Since it is OK, in the Church, to have personal opinions and also OK to teach - as long as we don't intentionally deceive - but we can't misrepresent our opinions as coming from the Church, there's nothing left but our opinions, because if even if we had something to quote directly from the Doctrine for the Congregation of the Faith 99% of the time it's going to be a bad translation.
So I wouldn't repeat that answer unless you absolutely have to.
